# How to do bitwise exclusive OR in sql server between two binary types?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

According this link:
[Bitwise Operators (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx)
we can do bitwise operation between binary and int, smallint, tinyint or vice versa.

But how can I make a bitwise exclusive OR in sql server between two binary types?
Or if this is not possible how can I split a binary/varbinary to individual bytes?

The reason I'm asking for this is because I need to xor two numbers bigger than max int value.
Thanks.

Comment: Tried and does not work: "The data types binary and binary are incompatible in the boolean XOR operator."

Comment: Isn't `a ^ b` equivalent to `(a | b) & !(a & b)`? Or am I having a derp moment here?

Comment: Yes, but bitwise restrictions of sql server are for all operations not just for XOR. See the link in the question.

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29207417/bitwise-operation-on-binary-datatypes.aspx) already (includes some abuse from Celko at the very idea and a couple of UDF suggestions)?

Comment: how many bits will it go up to/

Comment: @cyberkiwi - 16 bytes = 128 bits

@Martin - thanks for the link, I got the idea how to split the binary

Comment: @Martin to XOR only 16 bytes can be done in very few lines, but sure, it can be turned into UDF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All comments in code block

```
-- variables
declare @vb1 binary(16), @vb2 binary(16), @lo binary(8), @hi binary(8)

-- 2 guids to compare
declare @guid1 uniqueidentifier set @guid1 = '96B4316D-1EA7-4CA3-8D50-FEE8047C1329'
declare @guid2 uniqueidentifier set @guid2 = 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'

-- split every 8 bytes into a binary(8), which is a bigint, the largest size usable with XOR
select @vb1 = @guid1, @vb2 = @guid2

-- xor the high and low parts separately
select @hi = convert(binary(8), substring(@vb1,1,8)) ^ convert(bigint, substring(@vb2,1,8))
select @lo = convert(binary(8), substring(@vb1,9,8)) ^ convert(bigint, substring(@vb2,9,8))

-- the final result, concatenating the bytes using char(8) - binary -> uniqueidentifier
select 'A', @guid1 union all
select 'B', @guid2 union all
select 'A XOR B = ', convert(uniqueidentifier, convert(binary(16),convert(char(8),@hi) + convert(char(8),@lo)))
```

Comment: Might be outdate, but in the last line you can simplify it as 
select 'A XOR B = ', convert(uniqueidentifier, @hi + @lo)

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Bitwise Exclusive OR documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190277.aspx):

> **Note**
>
> Only one expression can be of either binary or varbinary data type
>   in a bitwise operation.

Comment: Do you know *why* this is the case? My guess would be uncertainty in the size of the returned variable...but it can't be larger than your largest passed in binary.

Answer (score 2):

The comment in the question from Martin, gave me an idea how to split binary so I can XOR the values.
Originally I wanted to XOR two GUIDs in sql. So here is the code I came with:

```
declare @guid1 uniqueidentifier
declare @guid2 uniqueidentifier
declare @guid3_hi binary(8)
declare @guid3_lo binary(8)
declare @guid3_temp varchar(32)
declare @guid3_char varchar(36)
declare @guid3 uniqueidentifier

set @guid1 = '96B4316D-1EA7-4CA3-8D50-FEE8047C1329'
set @guid2 = 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF'

set @guid3_hi = CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(@guid1 as binary(16)),1,8) as bigint) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(@guid2 as binary(16)),1,8) as bigint)
set @guid3_lo = CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(@guid1 as binary(16)),9,8) as bigint) ^ CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(@guid2 as binary(16)),9,8) as bigint)

set @guid3_temp = SUBSTRING(dbo.sp_hexadecimal(@guid3_hi), 3, 16) + SUBSTRING(dbo.sp_hexadecimal(@guid3_lo), 3, 16)
select @guid3_temp

set @guid3_char = SUBSTRING(@guid3_temp, 1, 8) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@guid3_temp, 9, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@guid3_temp, 13, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@guid3_temp, 17, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@guid3_temp, 21, 12)
select @guid3_char

set @guid3 = convert(uniqueidentifier, @guid3_char)
select @guid3

--result 92CE4B69-58E1-5CB3-72AF-0117FB83ECD6
```

The function to convert binary to hex string is from: [Converting Binary Data to Hexadecimal String](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104829)

I know that in SQL 2008 we can use convert function to do this as this post explained: [SQL Server 2008 : new binary – hex string conversion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/10/31/sql-server-2008-new-binary-hex-string-conversion-functionality-can-dramatically-improve-related-query-performance-by-orders-of-magnitude.aspx), but this was not an option in my case.

However it will be good if someone has a better idea how we can use SQL bitwise operations on binary data type.

EDIT:

Thanks to cyberkiwi for providing the correct algorithm and for point the error in my code.
This code could be good for XOR-ing binary but not for GUIDs, as GUIDs have different byte order for first and last 8 bytes. Please look at the wikipedia explanation for this: [GUID Basic structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guid#Basic_structure). Note that if you are going to use the XOR-ed result as real GUID you should take and into account the version bits.

Comment: Isn't this result wrong? The complement (XOR) of each byte should add up to F. 9+9 > F in the 1st pos. Compare the last 4 chars `1329 + ECD6 = FFFF`

Comment: @cyberkiwi of course the result is wrong, thanks for pointing that. I just overlooked the result as looking only at last 8 bytes which strangely are correct. The problem is casting an uniqueidentifier to binary which somehow did not convert the first 8 bytes correctly. It will be interesting to understand why this is happening and how we can convert uniqueidentifier to binary correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I used bigints for storing both values. This way you'll get more range. If the value is bigger than bigint, you might need to split the values in two bigint and use AND / OR operator combination.